# Find third level recursive

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-1.3

With :

```
function view($id = null) {
    if (!$id) {
        $this->Session->setFlash(__('Invalid Post', true));
        $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
    }
    $this->set('post', $this->Post->read(null, $id));

}
```

I can find related Users, but Users have Profile.

When I list related users, I want to have Profile Email instead of profile_id

```
Post $hasAndBelongsToMany Users $belongsTo Profile.
```

Tables:

Users

Posts_Users

Posts

Profiles.

ANSWER :

```
function view($id = null) {
    if (!$id) {
        $this->Session->setFlash(__('Invalid Post', true));
        $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
    }
    $this->Post->recursive =2;
    $this->set('post', $this->Post->read(null, $id));

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should not be using recursive 2, containable is the thing you want. http://book.cakephp.org/view/1323/Containable